# Setup/change RDP's default Output Queue?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rational-developer-for-i

After compiling Objects with Rational Developer(RDP), I inspect the "Commands Log" for success or failure.

**My Issue is that there is a lot of clutter, relating to "Printer device PRT01 not found.":**

```
Printer device PRT01 not found. Output queue changed to QPRINT in library QGPL.
Cause . . . . . :   The printer device PRT01 not found.  The output queue was changed for the spooled printer file QSYSPRT in library QSYS.
Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the following before you run the program again:
    -- Change or override the printer device name for the spooled printer file QSYSPRT in library QSYS using either the Change Printer File (CHGPRTF) command or the Override Printer File (OVRPRTF) command.
    -- Add or create the configuration for the printer (CRTDEVPRT command).
```

After doing some research. I noted that in DSPUSRPRF my Output queues are set to:

```
Print device . . . . . . . . . .   *WRKSTN       Name, *SAME, *WRKSTN, *SYSVAL 
Output queue . . . . . . . . . .   *WRKSTN       Name, *SAME, *WRKSTN, *DEV
```

My question is how do I setup/change RDP's default printer to be "QPRINT in library QGPL"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possibilities exist.  I personally would change the output queue in the user profile (CHGUSRPRF) because this profile will have this problem every place it is used.

Right click the connection, then select Subsystems on the left.  There are two tabs: Objects and Commands.  Click on Commands.  At the bottom of this panel is a field called 'Initial command'.  What I have there is CALL MYLIB/MYWDSCSETUP.  This is a short CL program that does things like set my output queue, environment variables, etc.  Very similar to the initial program that might run when you sign on to a 5250 terminal.

Comment: Thank you. For your suggestions. I was hoping for a preference I could set in RDP like one can for the usrprf, as I do not have Auth to change my usrprf.